# How to debug ng bootstrap package

Tags: angular, npm, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to debug ng-bootstrap 4 on an Angular 7 project so I followed [this](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/4_0_x/DEVELOPER.md)
instructions to clone ng-bootstrap and install its dependencies with yarn which finished without errors. After that, I went to my angular project and did an npm install [path to ng-bootstrap] and got the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@4.2.1 preinstall: `node misc/preinstall.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@4.2.1 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rinaldi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-08T02_15_19_801Z-debug.log
```

The log's tail presents the same thing. I've already tried deleted node_modules and got the same result. How do I surpass this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installed everything again but using yarn instead of npm. Added jasmine package to the project and changed `tsconfig.app.json` to code below.

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["jasmine"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",  
    "./node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.mock.ts"
  ]
}
```